# jQuery UI - autocomplete from a database

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-ui, autocomplete

What are the steps for having jQuery UI's autocomplete use a database?

Specifically, how do I pass this script the entered value? How does autocomplete receive the script's json?

What I know:

1) Change the 'source option' to a script that queries the database.
2) ?

Current code:

```
$("#searchInput input").autocomplete({
     source: "script_that_queries_the_db.php"
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

step 2? Have your php page `mysql_query` based on `$_GET['term']` and return the results using `json_encode`.

**Edit:** Also, make sure the array you pass to `json_encode` is a flat array, otherwise jQueryUI won't read it as well as we'd like without writing more custom code.

Comment: So the php page is automatically given the 'term' as a url parameter?

Comment: That's correct! Unless you'd like to change that, and in that case you need to specify the `source` option as a function

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to have your server return the results in json.  See this example:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote

Another way to do it is to make the request and parse the response yourself, by passing a function as source.  See this example:
http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-with-cache

In either case the data passed to autocomplete must be an array of objects each with a label and a value.